# Creating a view using join and DATEDIFF() in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, view, datediff

I am aware there are questions asked already regarding creating views with joins, and that is fine, except here I am trying to include a date difference.

I have a table  called 'appointments' and one called 'bill', with FK AppID.

I wish to create a view, consisting of the BillNo(Bill number), PatientID, and the Date

```
CREATE VIEW overdue_payments AS
    SELECT bill.BillNo, appointment.AppID, appointment.AppDate
        FROM bill,appointment
        WHERE bill.AppID=appointment.AppID
        AND DATEDIFF(AppDate, CURDATE())>30
```

That is used and the code implements but it does not add the test dates that are overdue:

```
CREATE VIEW overdue_payments2 AS

    SELECT bill.BillNo, appointment.AppID, appointment.AppDate
        FROM bill,appointment
        inner join appointment on bill.AppID=appointment.AppID
        where DATEDIFF(AppDate, CURDATE())>30
```

Then I attemppt to use an inner join, but get a 'non-unique table' error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean by "it does not add the test dates that are overdue"?  I don't see anything else in the rest of your question that addresses that.

Comment: I mean in the view I do not see the bills that are overdue. the view is empty

Comment: please provide a full [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first query used the long-deprecated comma cross-join syntax:

```
    FROM bill,appointment
    WHERE bill.AppID=appointment.AppID
```

To change that to modern, explicit join syntax, you want:

```
    FROM bill
    INNER JOIN appointment ON bill.AppID=appointment.AppID
```

but you've left the ",appointment" on your bill, so it is complaining that you are trying to join appointment twice without providing an alias.  Just remove the ",appointment".

Comment: thanks, but the view is still empty. there is no complaint so to speak, creates view, but its empty

Comment: your query should return any appointments that have bills and have an AppDate more than 30 days in the future.  maybe there are no such appointments?  what is overdue and how do you want to determine it?

Comment: I had to swap DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), AppDate)>30. But you helped thank you!